# PHP: string does not equal string

Tags: php, csv, encoding, ascii

**The Project:**

I'm parsing a CSV file and am inserting its data into a database. In a loop I take the CSV values and validate them (make sure they're populated), and the values are stored like this:

```
$current_order_number = $array[$i]['order_number'] ?? null;
```

("order_number" is the name of a header inside the CSV file.)

**The Problem:**

When I manually typed "order_number", $current_order_number was null.

When I copied "order_number" from the CSV file $current_order_number was correct.

(This is the only CSV header that does this. I manually typed the rest and they work perfectly.)

**Debugging:**

I used a string-to-ASCII converter and found that the correct string ("order_number") converted into:

```
NULL 111 114 100 101 114 95 110 117 109 98 101 114
```

While the incorrect string ("order_number") converted into

```
111 114 100 101 114 95 110 117 109 98 101 114
```

I tried (to remove the null):

```
$value = str_replace("\0", "", $value);
```

And (thinking it was the encoding):

```
$value = utf8_encode($value);
```

with no luck.

**Full Code:**

```
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['csv_raw']['name'] );

if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv_raw']['tmp_name'], $target_path) ) {
  echo "File Upload Successful: -- [" . $target_path . "] --\r\n";
  $array = $fields = array();
  $i = 0;
  $handle = @fopen($target_path, "r");
  if ($handle) {
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
      if (empty($fields)) {
        $fields = $row;
        continue;
      }
      foreach ($row as $k=>$value) {
        if (strlen(trim($value)) == 0) {
          $value = 0;
        }
        $value = str_replace("\0", "", $value);
        $array[$i][$fields[$k]] = $value;
      }
      //print_r($array[$i]);
      //"order_number"(correct [NULL 111 114 100 101 114 95 110 117 109 98 101 114])
      //"order_number" (incorrect [111 114 100 101 114 95 110 117 109 98 101 114])
      $current_order_number = $array[$i]['order_number'] ?? null;
      $current_order_line = $array[$i]['order_line'] ?? null;
      $current_shipment_number = $array[$i]['shipment_number'] ?? null;
      $current_package_number = $array[$i]['package_number'] ?? null;
      $current_package_item_number = $array[$i]['package_item_num'] ?? null;
      $current_item_code = $array[$i]['item_code'] ?? null;
      $current_quantity = $array[$i]['qty_shipped'] ?? null;
      $query = query("SELECT * FROM `osl` WHERE `order_number` = ".$current_order_number." AND `item_code` = ".$current_item_code." ");
      confirm($query);

      if (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0) {
        $query = query("SELECT * FROM `osl_daily` WHERE `order_number` = ".$current_order_number." AND `item_code` = ".$current_item_code." ");
        confirm($query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0) {
          $query = query("
          INSERT INTO `osl_daily` (`local_id`, `order_number`, `order_line`, `shipment_number`, `package_number`, `package_item_number`,`item_code`, `quantity`)
          VALUES (NULL,".$current_order_number.",".$current_order_line.",".$current_shipment_number.",".$current_package_number.",".$current_package_item_number.",".$current_item_code.",".$current_quantity.")
          ");
          confirm($query);
          echo "Success: Order Number ".$current_order_number." Lines Have Been Imported Successfully.\r\n";
        }
        else {
          echo "Error: Order Number ".$current_order_number." Line Already Exists in osl_daily.\r\n";
        }
      }
      else {
        echo "Error: Order Number ".$current_order_number." Line Already Exists in osl.\r\n";
      }

      $i++;
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
      echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\r\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
  }
}
else {
  echo "Error: File Upload Failed\r\n";
}
```

**CSV Code:**
    order_number,order_line,shipment_number,package_number,package_item_num,item_code,qty_shipped
    43441,1,37294,1,1,10000,1
    43441,2,37294,1,2,10010,1

Why doesn't "order_number" = "order_number"? And how do I make order_number = order_number?

Comment: Maybe if you show us the real code rather than a line or 2 from here and there we could be a bit more helpful

Comment: Is your `$i` being set correctly?

Comment: Updated question. The literal text "order_number" is the problem

Comment: Can you also post a sample of the csv file, just s few lines shoudl be enough

Comment: Done @RiggsFolly

Comment: Somehow your csv seems to start with a nullbyte. Can you remove it? Alternatively you could try to access the value with `$array[$i]["\0order_number"]`(double quotes!)

Comment: How do I remove it? in terms of code. I can't manually remove it every time I run the program

Comment: You could always just use the value from the header - `$current_order_number = $array[$i][$fields[0]] ?? null;`, just assumes it will always be the first field.

Comment: @simon.ro I can not access it with `$array[$i]["\0order_number"]`.

Comment: @NigelRen That works, I wish I could fix the text as I'm not sure this won't appear throughout the csv. BUT your solution did work

Comment: Try printing out the field char by char - `foreach ( str_split($fields[0]) as $k => $chr ) {  echo $k."-".ord($chr)."=".$chr.PHP_EOL;  }`

Comment: @NigelRen This is the output `0-239=�
1-187=�
2-191=�
3-111=o
4-114=r
5-100=d
6-101=e
7-114=r
8-95=_
9-110=n
10-117=u
11-109=m
12-98=b
13-101=e
14-114=r`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first three characters seem to be the problem. You have characters 239, 187 and 191 at the beginning of the file.  Having a look for this combination of codes seems to give a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM) for UTF-8.

The easy way of dealing with this would be to just remove them off the first field if present...

```
if (empty($fields)) {
    if ( substr($row[0],0,3) === chr(239).chr(187).chr(191))    {
        $row[0] = substr($row[0], 3);
    }
    $fields = $row;
    continue;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

We can use str_contains to get the matched string as well.
The function checks the string and returns a boolean true in case it exists and false otherwise.

```
  if (str_contains($str, $substr)) {
            return "PHP string contains '$str'";
        } else {
            return "PHP string does not contain '$substr";
        }
```